# Wordpress Permalink Custom Url /index.php/%postname is working while /%postname is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have uploaded my website to the server and when i am trying to change permalink, it is working only with `/index.php/%postname`.

Neither `/index.php/%postname/%` is working nor `/%postname/*` is working.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put below code in .htaccess file in wordpress site directory. verify similar code is already present in .htaccess file or not. If present please replace with below code. if no .htaccess file is present please create one with following code.

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```